# How to setup cron job for a /shell script?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, shell

As it says in the title:

I have a script in shell that runs a report by using this command in CLI:

```
php /shell/myscript.php --profile 1
```

Now, i want to add it to `crontab` so it will be something like this:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f PATH_TO_FILE/myscript.php --profile 1
```

But the above command is incorrect, and in the same time this is how magento works with this shell scripts, so i don't know how to proceed from here:

Any ideas?

Comment: "But the above command is incorrect" - what error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell scripts often contain `require 'abstract.php';`, so they must be run within the `shell` directory itself. In that case, use a crontab like this:

```
0 * * * * cd /path/to/magento/shell && php myscript.php --whatever
```

Comment: i tried the following: `*/10 * * * * cd /home/path/to/shell && php run_data_flow_profile.php --profile 26` but it's not working, no errors in `/var/log/cron` and the same command works if i put it manually in console/terminal. any ideas ?

Comment: try `/usr/bin/php` (or whatever the path to your PHP binary is), the PATH environment variable might not be available. If that still does not work, I suspect a problem within your PHP script

Comment: thanks fabian, i've tried also with the path to PHP bin but still doesn't work, if the script have some issues then it shouldn't be working manually also right ? any other ideas to try ?

Comment: when i run with /usr/bin/php i get this: `Error in argument 3, char 2: no argument for option -`

Comment: i was referring the wrong bin, thank you for help, worked like a charm!